# Discrete math truth tables.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

> Calculate according to truth tables:
>
> $(0 ⇒ 1)$ $⇒$ $[0∧ \lnot (1 ∨ 0)]$

How should I solve this?

Looks like there are no variables here.

Comment: What do you even mean by "solve" here? What is your goal?

Comment: @HenningMakholm, to find the truth table for this.

Comment: x @anonymous: What do you mean by "truth table" for something that does not depend on any variables? A table with a single row and a single column?

Comment: This was given in the class: "Calculate according to truth tables:

(0 ⇒ 1) ⇒ [0∧ ∼ (1 ∨ 0)]". I need some clue to solve it.

Comment: Use the truth table for $\lor$ to compute $1 \lor 0$, and so on.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, That means, it would only be one column. Right?

Comment: just use the rules learned in class.. 1∨0 is 1 etc..

Comment: Can you compute e.g. $[0 \times - (1 + 0)]$ ? It is the same: use the "arithmetic" of [truth tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table#Truth_table_for_all_binary_logical_operators) instead of elementary arithmetic.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, what does it mean by (0⇒1)  ?

Comment: This was given in the class: "Calculate according to truth tables"... this presupposes that the truth tables for the boolean connectives have been "introduced" to you.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, I solved it. The result is 0. But,  what does it mean by (0⇒1)

Comment: See [truth table for implication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table#Logical_implication) : $\to$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's right, there are no variables here.  This question would be analogous to:

"Calculate 3 * ( 4 + 7)"

In other words, just work out the truth-values (sometimes this is called 'evaluation' rather than 'calculation'):

(0 ⇒ 1) 
⇒ [0∧ ∼ (1 ∨ 0)] = 1 
⇒ [0∧ ∼ 1] = 1 
⇒ [0∧ 0] = 1 
⇒ 0 = 0

P.S. increased readability.

Comment: How is (0 ⇒ 1) relevant here?

Comment: @anonymous It's just that $0 \Rightarrow 1 = 1$ by the definition of the truth-table for $\Rightarrow$